# What do clean Touhou installs look like?

Tags: touhou-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil

I've been looking for a clean install of EoSD for days, but everything is English- patched. I haven't been able to find a single clean install of it. I also can't read enough Japanese to ask online. What files make up a clean EoSD install?

Comment: i can't say for certain which exact installation of eosd you got your fingers on, but the most common ones include two .exe files, names *eosd.exe* or *th06.exe* for the original one and *th06e.exe* for the english patched one. if your installation looks anything like that, try running the original ones and see if it works. there is a chance you need to set your locale to japan in order to run them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a full clean version of the game but you can find the trial version on ZUN's website.

http://www16.big.or.jp/~zun/html/th06.html

It has a folder with html and images of the manual but other than a trial information text file and the missing BGM folder, it seems like it just has the Japanese names of the config, DAT and main exe filew.

I would say the full vanilla version would have

1. BGM folder with WAV files
2. Manual Folder
3. custom.exe and custom.txt
4. Japanese version of the game exe, DAT and cfg file. When I got these they all started with ìgûéï¢ which is incorrectly encoded text. The translated version has th06 instead so it's probably the Japanese name of EoSD.

If you really want to see what the full game has, you can try and import a copy or something.